# Find Raster data in a Mapinfo workspace

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I want to check if there is a raster layer in a map window using Mapbasic v2019.

For Group Layers I use the following but I want to do the equivalent with Rasters.

```
Sub Remove_Group (ByVal Group_Name as String)
OnError GoTo GroupError
dim mapwindowid,groupid,groupcount,x as integer

mapwindowid = FrontWindow()
groupid = MapperInfo( mapwindowid, 29) '29 is MAPPER_INFO_GROUPLAYERS
x=1
while x <=groupcount
    if GroupLayerInfo ( mapwindowid, groupid, 1 ) = Group_Name then '1 is GROUPLAYER_INFO_NAME
        x=x+1
    End If
Wend

groupcount = GroupLayerInfo (mapwindowid, groupid, 5)  '5 is GROUPLAYER_INFO_ALL_LAYERS
'print ("GroupCount is: "&groupcount)
if groupcount=0 then
    Set Map Window mapwindowid GroupLayer Group_Name Ungroup
End if

OnError GoTo 0
Exit Sub
GroupError:
Print ("=== An error has occured - please take a screen grab and email the following text to support@mangoesmapping.com.au"&chr$(13)&"Error Code is "& Err()& " | " & Error$()&chr$(13))
Resume Next

End Sub
```

For `groupid = MapperInfo( mapwindowid, 29) '29 is MAPPER_INFO_GROUPLAYERS` I need to find a function to see if the data is raster or vector in MapperInfo

I see `LayerInfo` has `LAYER_INFO_TYPE` that has value 2 for raster images but then I need to list each layer from mapperinfo and then check each one if it's type 2. There should be an easier way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to loop through the layers in your map and check the type of each.

```
mapwindowid = FrontWindow()
For layerid = MapperInfo( mapwindowid, MAPPER_INFO_LAYERS) To 1 Step -1
    if LayerInfo( mapwindowid, layerid, LAYER_INFO_TYPE) In (LAYER_INFO_TYPE_IMAGE, LAYER_INFO_TYPE_GRID, LAYER_INFO_TYPE_WMS, LAYER_INFO_TYPE_TILESERVER)  then 
        Print "Map has raster layer!"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Note that I check the layer against all raster layer types: image, grid, WMS, and Tile Server.